# Simple latex book template

Tags: templates, books

I need to write a book in (after trimmed) size 234mm tall x 156mm wide. Text block should be proportional to trimmed size, centered to page. Typeface to be used is Utopia with regular lining number for number on table and old style number for number elsewhere. Font for text body is Utopia 10pt, for chapter (heading) is Utopia 17pt and title (subheading) is Utopia 13pt. Leading/line-height for each font size should be the good pair, e.g. 10pt/13pt. The chapters and titles are unnumbered. Chapter is always on recto page. For every page where Chapter begins, TOC, List of Figure, other front matter, there will be no page number. In other pages in mainmatter, page number is at the header (the header space should be inside text block). There will be no margin note, only footnote where needed. Foot note should be Utopia 8pt, with superscripted footnote mark, indented. FYI, the book will not have any mathematical equation, just texts, some pictures and tables.

I am new to TeX and LaTeX, but would like to try the book classes. I saw Memoir and its manual was frightening enough for me. To achieve above, which class should be simpler? Any code you may suggest?

Intend to achieve this page layout:

- Right hand w/ Chapter:

  [image]
- Left hand:

  [image]

Appreciate any help/input.

Comment: I think that you should separate this big “question” into several little one which have one precise goal. For example, one question for the paper size, one question for the font, etc. I will add that these question may already have been answer, here on TeX.sx or elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: `\documentclass{book}\begin{document}<content\end{document}`; you wanted something, simple, right? This is expandabe using one of the many LaTeX packages.

Comment: I am not a typography expert, yet am I an enthusiast, but simple-looking typography is not necessarily simple to achieve.

Comment: You might not be aware of it, but what you are asking for is what others charge some serious money for. http://www.latextypesetting.com/ In its current state, nobody will prepare a complete answer and your chances are *much* higher if you address each point in a separate question.

Comment: Invest in a good LaTeX book for beginners. I recommend Marc van Dongen's [*LaTeX and Friends*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642238154) which is quite up to date and very comprehensive. Then go back to the `memoir` manual. It will be less frightening, and can easily allow you to achieve everything you want to do without too much fuss.   LaTeX requires some initial learning, but for fairly simply documents the learning curve need not be so steep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always provide some code where you have started; writing down your requirements doesn't really help.  OTOH, vanilla LaTeX doesn't have a good support for multi-author books.  This is a starting point for you mostly based on `titlesec` package.  You have to use the command `\chapauthor{name}` before `\chapter` command when you have an author, otherwise `\chapauthor{}` for things like `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  textwidth  = 156mm ,
  textheight = 234mm ,
  a4paper            ,
  includehead        ,
  hcentering         ,
  vcentering
}

\usepackage[osf,proportional,space]{erewhon}
\usepackage[rigidchapters,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc,lipsum,multicol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\chap@author{}
\newcommand\chapauthor[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \gdef\chap@author{#1}%
}
\def\chap@author{}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\LARGE\bfseries\filright}
  {\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {%
    \ifx\chap@author\@empty\else
      \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%
      \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,-17){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\Large\mdseries\itshape \chap@author}}
      \end{picture}%
    \fi
  }
  [%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \ifx\chap@author\@empty\else
      \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \vspace{-5pt}%
        \protect\contentsline{chapter}{\mdseries\itshape \chap@author}{}{}%
      }%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{5pt}}%
    \fi
    \startcontents
  ]

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\Large\bfseries\filright}
  {\thesection}
  {0pt}
  {}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{.75pc}{.5pc}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \sethead[%
    \ifx\chap@author\@empty
      {\makebox[1.5pc][l]{\thepage}{\lsstyle\MakeUppercase\chaptertitle}}%
    \else
      {\makebox[1.5pc][l]{\thepage}{\lsstyle\MakeUppercase\chap@author}}%
    \fi]
    [][]
    {}{}{}
}

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em%
  \noindent
  \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark\hspace{0.5em}}#1}

\let\footnoterule\relax

\makeatother

\usepackage[activate=true]{microtype}

\pagestyle{main}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\chapauthor{Christoper S. Chapman}
\chapter{Controlling Strategy}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\subsubsection*{Contents of this chapter}]
   \printcontents{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{multicols}

Norman 1965, Kaplan 1987 \\\lipsum[1]

Footnotes look like\footnote{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste
  natus error si.  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error,
  si.  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error si.}
and\footnote{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error si.  Sed
  ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error, si.  Sed ut
  perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error si.}.

\section{The relationship between management control systems and
  strategy}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Any Relationship between management control systems and
  strategy?}
\lipsum[1]

\section{No Relationship between management control systems and
  strategy!}
\lipsum

\chapauthor{}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

> [image]